# How to know if a class belongs to bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, visual-studio-code, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

How do I know if a class such as `mt-3` or `table-left` belongs to bootstrap or not?

Is there something like a website or tool, or something inside VSCode that helps me to check if a class is a bootstrap keyword or not?

Comment: Use a bootstrap cheat sheet https://hackerthemes.com/bootstrap-cheatsheet/

Comment: Enter "bootstrap [class name]" into your favorite search engine (browser address bar). Presto.

Answer (score 1):

1. Open your inspector via right click "inspect".
2. Then select the element you are targeting.
3. Next look at the classes it has
4. search if bootstrap has those classes to via their documentation or via google

Manual labor required. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if VSCode has a built in check but you can always just type in the class at the search bar at https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.1/getting-started/introduction/ and if it shows something there it is a bootstrap class.